# I want to change the text with sed editor

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

How can replace text with Linux shell (`sed`, `awk`, ...)

Input:

```
aaa decimal(6,3) null,
bbb decimal(12,3) not null,
ccc decimal(1,11) null,
ddd decimal(2,10) null,
ff  decimal(10,1) null,
```

I want replace `decimal(X,Y)` with `decimal`:

```
aaa decimal null,
bbb decimal not null,
ccc decimal null,
ddd decimal null,
ff  decimal null,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

```
sed -r 's/(decimal)\([^)]*\)/\1/' filename
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
aaa decimal null,
bbb decimal not null,
ccc decimal null,
ddd decimal null,
ff  decimal null,
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sed 's/(.*)//' infile.txt
```

Comment: your answer is running but input char(10), output char (i want remove/replace only decimal (x,y))

Comment: sed 's/decimal([^)]*)/decimal/' infile.txt

Comment: You assume that all line has the same format.  What about `aaa(4,3) decimal(5,6) null,

Answer (score 2):

If every line is equal and does contain `decimal` you could do:

```
awk '$2="decimal"' file
aaa decimal null,
bbb decimal not null,
ccc decimal null,
ddd decimal null,
ff decimal null,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e 's/decimal\(.*?\)/decimal/g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk '/decimal/{gsub(/\(.*\)/,"")}1' file
```